How to make water Fluid simulation fade out quicker
in Which of the settings can I control the fluid which makes the water fade quicker. The fluid water remains on my object, which I want the water to slip off my object to drip into the water pool. I have set the frames of the object to collide from 0 to 50, then make the water drip.


